# css fluid fluid fluid layout

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to achieve something quite tricky in CSS, but also quite "simple" :

[image]

### Explanation:

Some element with text inside it (unknown width) with 2 elements on each side of it, both occupying the remaining space.

I thought of going with `display:table` for the container and for the 3 children going `display:table-cell` but it just doesn't work, or I don't know how to use it properly..

Comment: Show us your html code and we can go from there.

Comment: @CarolMcKay his question is conceptually, not based off of failed implementations.

Comment: ok I've put a link to a playground

Comment: Maybe flexbox would help here..

Comment: @Ben flexbox is not even a standard, it's only an experiment some vendors are playing with, the spec can be changed tomorrow as far as i know...

Comment: @vsync - I don't think you're right about that. After three major revisions, I think it has now been standardized. It seems [flexbox has reached candidate recommendation on September 18](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).

Comment: I would prefer to wait, support is still weak: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @vsync - True. It's just that you said that it's not a standard and that it's just an experiment... Well, I couldn't resist my inner desire to [well-actually](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html) you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Demo playground

### HTML

```
<header>
  <h1>Some title</h1>
</header>
```

### CSS

```
header{ 
  display:table;
  text-align:center; 
  width:50%; 
}
header:before, header:after{ 
  content:'';
  display:table-cell; 
  background:red; 
  width:50%;
  border-radius:5px; 
}
header > h1{ white-space:pre; padding:0 10px; }
```

Comment: @vsync added in his demo also transitions, that transformed this demo into pure art

Answer (score 2):

This is using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to make this bar and text.

**HTML**

```
<div class="textBarContainer">
    <div class="textBarBefore"></div>
    <div class="textBar">Text</div>
    <div class="textBarAfter"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.textBarContainer {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.textBar {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 10px;
    white-space: pre;
}
.textBarAfter, .textBarBefore {
    background: #cc0000;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    content:' ';
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E2Vtr/1/)**

Comment: nope nope, tried this...fail. put a sentence not just one word. you can't just say both sides are 50%..

Comment: wait! if I force the text with `white-space:pre` it will work.

Answer (score -4):

```
<ul class="columnlayout">
 <li>
   <div>Left content</div>
 </li>

 <li class="centercontent">
   <div>middle text content</div>
 </li>

 <li>
   <div>Right content</div>
 </li>
</ul>

//columns layout
ul.columnlayout
{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    list-style-type: none;

    > li
    {
        float:left;
        margin:0;
        list-style-type:none;
                    width:200px;

                    &.centercontent
                    {
                       width:auto;
                    }

        ul.xoxo
        {
            list-style-type: none;

            li
            {
                list-style-type: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

oh, pardon my .scss!

```
ul.columnlayout {
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    list-style-type: none;
   }

  ul.columnlayout li {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:200px;
  }

    ul.columnlayout li.centercontent {
      width:auto;
    }
```

Comment: @vsync - It`s scss, wake up man ;) Much easier than plain css.